# Smoother sprite rotation in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a simple program where when you hold the screen the sprite moves up and when you let go the sprite moves down. So in the ccTouchesBegan function I rotate the sprite:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    player.rotation = -5;
}
```

And then in the ccTouchesEnded function I rotate it again:

```
-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    player.rotation = 20;
}
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to make the rotation a little slower and smoother? It looks very clunky when I run it and I want it to look more realistic. I am not using a physics engine (box2d, chipmunk, etc..)

Comment: What type of object is `player`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use CCRotateBy or CCRotateTo Class functions to rotate it.
  Ex. player->runAction(CCRotateTo::create(1.0f, -5)); // In C++

  Here first parameter specifies duration to rotation (currently 1 sec) and 2nd one is for Angle.

  But if you touch the screen too frequently this one also may look weird.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is for cocos2d-IOS. But you can translate it for c++ also. its easy.

```
    CCRotateBy *rotTouchBegin = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1.0f angle:-5];
    CCRotateBy *rotTouchEnd = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1.0f angle:20];

    -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
      {
         [player stopAllActions];             
         [player rotTouchBegin];
      }

    -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
         [player stopAllActions];
         [player rotTouchEnd];
```

}

If you dont want to stop all the actions running on the player then just tag your actions so that you can use 
        [player stopAction:[player getActionByTag:]];